# Undo in script does not work?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to undo an operation in a script but the `bpy.ops.ed.undo()` does not work.
The **exactly same sequence** of statements run **in Python Console** works as expected.

A code that demonstrates this behavior is this (run from Text editor):

```
import bpy

# ... already in Edit mode, selected all

bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold = 0.1)
# the above says "Info: Removed 30 vertices"

# create new undo step (without this it doesn't work in Python Console either)
bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()

# this undo does nothing ...
bpy.ops.ed.undo()

# because this ...
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold = 0.1)
# says "Info: Removed 0 vertices"
```

Interestingly enough the pushed undo step is visible in Undo History right before the Run Script step - and it can be undone, of course.

**Is there a catch I'm missing here?**

Comment: Nobody? Should I post this on Stackoverflow instead?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/how-can-i-get-an-objects-previous-location-with-python/159892#159892 the last half answers this I guess